# Does the "Preview" in Assistant Editor removed from Xcode at latest update?

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode have a 'Preview', which you can configure the localization and different device version of iOS, but I found out it seems to be removed from the Xcode,

[image]

It should show up right in the bottom as usual.

I am not sure if I fiddled with some settings here, or It just had been removed.

Anyone know why it is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may be removed on Xcode 14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preview only shows up as an option when you have a storyboard file selected. In your screenshot you have the main project file selected, so there is nothing to preview.